# OS X 10.10.. . backup program does not recognize/read prior backups

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

The backup program does not recognize data I copied to a new 3T TimeCapsule disk. When I select the folder containing the data, the program tells me there are no prior backups, but there are over 875MB of data there.

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: You should just be able to tell Time Machine which drive to use - it ought to figure it out from there, so long as it can see backups.backupdb at the top level.

Comment: That's the problem. I selected the drive TimeMachine should use and when ready to start a new backup, it shows there are not prior backups although I know the backup folder contains >875MB of data. The program can't figure it out. The backup folder was copied as a sub folder - it is not at the top level; when copying it, the system did not allow to put it at the top.

Comment: Pretty sure it wants to see it at the top

Comment: As well as needing to be at the top, a simple drag and drop in Finder will mess it up.  I take it you mean 875GB - 875MB is a very small backup.